# Include/exclude don't work

Tags: webpack

Webpack 2.2.0

I include/exclude file/folder in my config, but webpack keeps bundling that was excluded:

the folder structure

```
src/
  index.js // entry point
server/
  test.js // file for testing
build/
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const SRC = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src')
const BUILD = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './build')

module.exports = {
  context: SRC,
  entry: {
    main: './'
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: SRC,
      exclude: path.resolve(process.cwd(), './server’), // even explicit excluding changes nothing
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  }
}
```

./src/index.js

```
import func from ‘../server/test.js’ // this must not be imported
func() // working
```

./server/test.js

```
export default function () { console.log(`I’m in the bundle`) } // this is being executed
```

I see the message in the browser console.

Comment: Webpack can't exclude something that you are importing and using in your `index.js`

Comment: What `exclude` and `include` options are then intended for?

Comment: You can read a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823764/how-include-and-exclude-works-in-webpack-loader Btw you're testing for `.jsx` but your files are `js`

Comment: I'm testing for both, there is a question mark in the regexp.

Comment: My bad sorry. Didn't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the answer is if you `include/exclude` something in the webpack config it won't be transformed by the loader but it will be imported into the bundle. To completely exclude something from bundling you need to use `module.noParse` option: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-noparse

Comment: This answer does not seem to be entirely correct -- `module.noParse` does not "exclude [...] from bundling". Per the docs linked, it is mainly a performance optimization that skips _parsing_ of modules. It is very much still bundled, just not parsed. To "exclude" modules from a bundle, you'd want to use [`IgnorePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/). Per the docs, `IgnorePlugin` will "prevent generation of modules for" the given regex.