# webpack 2 + babel loader config - should production config exclude node_modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to understand the webpack 2 and babel-loader documentation but I'm confused by the `exclude` option..

Here's what I mean:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  use: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: 'node_modules',
  include: 'app'
}
```

Include will use that loader to process the files that match in `'app'`, but do I need to do this for `node_modules`?

THanks

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823764/how-include-and-exclude-works-in-webpack-loader. TL;DR: Files in node_modules are likely already transformed, so you don't want to transform them again (and thus you `exclude` them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How "include" and "exclude" works in webpack loader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823764/how-include-and-exclude-works-in-webpack-loader)