# Load coffee script module in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, coffeescript, angular-cli

I'm having a *Angular-CLI* application and I try to bring in a third party dependency in, which is written in *Coffee Script*. This is what I do in my component:

```
const CoffeeWidget = require('coffee-loader!CoffeeWidget');
```

I thought using a coffee loader would work. But not really. Now I'm able to read the `index.coffee`, but in my `index.coffee` I `require` other coffee files. Like:

```
Cup = require '../tools/cup.coffee'
```

But it has problems to ready the `cup.coffee` and says: `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Comment: I don't think that it is just simple as requiring the `.coffee` file, you need to transpile it to TS first. You can use this tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-script-to-typescript

Comment: This seems not to be supported anymore by the developers. And how would I do this without running this step always before compiling my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `coffee-loader` directly into your [require statement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#via-require), webpack will use the loader just on the required file.

In order let webpack use `coffee-loader` on any `.coffee` file found at any depth, extend the `module.rules` array in your webpack configuration with:

```
// Webpack 2 syntax

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.coffee$/,
        use: [ 'coffee-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This has helped a lot! Thanks! But there is still one little thing. The CoffeeScript Widget is a third party tool. Now, it is not requiring its dependency strictly like `Cup = require '../tools/cup.coffee'`, but `Cup = require '../tools/cup`. So basically the `.coffee` is missing. Is the `.coffee` mandatory? The compiler won't compile without it, but I don't want to make changes to a third party lib.

Comment: Since the module you're importing is a published third party tool, it should come with a precompiled version ready to be imported in vanilla JS. This is usually the best practice with 3rd party code. Does your plugin miss that?

Comment: `/\.coffee$/` is just a regex which Webpack runs against each requirish-file to chose the loader to use. You might try to write a proper regex to let `coffe-loader` just targeting the files required by your plugin.

Also consider to declare [`include` or `exclude` loader options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823764/how-include-and-exclude-works-in-webpack-loader), too.

Comment: I'm in contact with the developer of the coffee-script lib. In that case, it might be the best to ask him to compile it. I wasn't sure myself, if I've to compile it or if I should receive a compiled version.

Comment: Ah! And just on a site node. You say that such libraries should always be precompiled. Would you say the same for react components? By nature the end with jsx and angular can't really deal with that.

Comment: Yep, the same goes for React components. JSX tags are converted into `React.createElement` calls.

Comment: Cool! Do you have a reference to the best practices by any chance? So I can point this out a little bit more.