# Is Angular(Angular4) compatible with coffeescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, coffeescript

Can I use coffee script instead of typescript in my Angular 4 application?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. There are ways you can ([Load coffee script module in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626620/load-coffee-script-module-in-angular) ), but it would be better to use typescript for a number is reasons:

- Documentation (there is not a complete documentation for angular in javascript)
- popularity http://www.npmtrends.com/typescript-vs-coffeescript
- typscript offer really nice features

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm not sure what you mean by this: "there is not a complete documentation for angular in javascript"

Comment: I mean if you go here https://angular.io/docs it says that most examples are on typscript and new documentation is first released with typescript