# How to optionally process code in node_modules with babel-loader in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

This is a follow up from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37833072/931860).

I have some 3rd party code (react components) that I bundle as ES modules (using the `pkg.module` entry point). This works great (you get module concatenation and tree shaking), but the included code isn't transpiled with babel because, following most config examples, I exclude `node_modules` in the babel-loader section of my webpack config like this:

```
{
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    ...
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

So, I get unexpected token errors when I run webpack. Based on the linked answer, I switched from using an `exclude` to an `include` to optionally bring in some packages from `node_modules` like this:

```
{
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: [/node_modules\/@my-scope/, /src/],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    ...
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

This seems to be working for me (no more, unexpected token errors when I run webpack), but I'm not 100% sure it's doing what I think it is.

Does this solution look right? Is there a better way?

Comment: The solution looks ok to me. If the include begins to get complex, you could replace it with a function and use logic to filter there.

Comment: Thanks @JuhoVepsäläinen, I appreciate that. Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution looks ok to me. If the include begins to get complex, you could replace it with a function and use logic to filter there.